# Why do I not see CREATE or CREATE2 opcodes in traces of contract creating transactions?

Tags: contract-deployment, opcode, transaction-trace, create

I am trying to see smart contract creations from opcodes in transaction traces with `debug_traceTransaction`. But traces of transactions that created contracts do not seem to include the `CREATE` opcode.

Example:

CryptoKitties’ core contract is: `0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d`

It was created with this transaction: `0x691f348ef11e9ef95d540a2da2c5f38e36072619aa44db0827e1b8a276f120f4`

I would expect to see the creation of the contract in the transaction trace indicated by the `CREATE` or `CREATE2` opcode according to the Yellow Paper pp. 37f (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).
The Python code I am using is:

```
from web3 import Web3
tx= "0x691f348ef11e9ef95d540a2da2c5f38e36072619aa44db0827e1b8a276f120f4"
web3 = Web3.HTTPProvider("endpoint")
trace = web3.make_request('debug_traceTransaction', [tx])
```

The output trace is fairly long but does not include `CREATE` or `CREATE2`.

Am I using the wrong transaction or the wrong debug trace?
How do I find the trace with the `CREATE` or `CREATE2` opcode (e.g., for CryptoKitties' core contract)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I not see CREATE or CREATE2 opcodes in traces of contract creating transactions?

because this contract is NOT created using CREATE or CREATE2 opcode, it is created by sending `nil` in the 'To' field of the transaction. To see an example of CREATE2 opcode check out UniswapV3PoolDeployer contract, it uses CREATE2 opcode.

Answer (score 0):

The contract in the question was created by an EOA as @Nulik's answer describes.

`CREATE` and `CREATE2` opcodes are how a contract can create another contract.

An EOA creates a contract by sending a transaction 'To' an empty address, but with "Input Data" being the "initialisation EVM code" of the contract being created.

In the Yellow Paper (currently Berlin Version) this is described in section `7. CONTRACT CREATION`.  In Etherscan, you can see the "Input Data" of the transaction by "Click to see More".